# Can I change button position depending on the cursor position?

Tags: html, css, button, position, cursor

I'm new to javascript yet, so unfortunatelly I'm not aware of the proper commands in it yet.
So I have this code, with a button which scrolls back to the top, and I'd like to know if there's a way to change the position of that button depending where the cursor is? For example if the cursor is on the right side of the site, the button appears on the right side.
I'm not expecting you to write the code itself if it's long, it's enough if you can tell me what commands I need to use, then I'll try to do it myself

I appriciate any help!

```
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="topB" title="Go to top">Top</button>



#topB {
display: none; 
position: fixed; 
bottom: 20px; 
right: 30px; 
z-index: 99; 
border: none; 
outline: none; 
background-color: gray; 
color: white; 
cursor: pointer; 
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 18px; 
}

#topB:hover {
color:black;
background-color: red; 
}


window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
// After scrolling down "number"px, the button appears
if (document.body.scrollTop >= 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 
10) {
    document.getElementById("topB").style.display = "block";
} else {
    document.getElementById("topB").style.display = "none";
}
}
function topFunction() {
// Scrolls to the top on click
document.body.scrollTop = 0; 
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; 
}
```

Comment: For starters: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp. You can hide and show the buttons on different divs according to the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mousehover event and get the x and y co ordinates of the pointer. now get total width of screen using window.innerWidth now using x position of pointer determine i  which half pointer is and change css accordingly. i can help you if you need more help

Comment: Could you help me a bit if you don't mind?
So I made this code(not in 6hrs ofc, only had freetime now)
      `function buttonchangeP(event){
 var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
 if(x<=950){
  document.getElementById("topBR").style.right="30px";
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("topBR").style.left="30px" ;
 }
        }`
It does change the button position, but only once
What should I add to it so it would do it nonstop?

Comment: Nevermind, solved it, just had to replace the right with left, and in the else part set the the px to  higher number,(1800px in this case)